# StringTemplate ListDictionary Iteration

Tags: c#, stringtemplate

I'm trying to iterate over a ListDictionary (C# StringTemplate) in a template and have each list item invoke another template:

```
DataDefAssign(cols) ::=
<<
<cols.keys: { k | <PropDef(name=<k>, type=<cols.(k)>) }>
>>
```

The above template does not generate anything.
If I inline an anonymous template instead of trying to invoke the PropDef template it works as expected. Does the iteration only allow anonymous templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a syntax issue.  The iteration should be:

```
<cols.keys: { k | <PropDef(name=k, type=cols.(k))> }>
```

Thanks to micha-1@fantasymail.de for pointing this out on the StringTemplate list.